Is there terminology to distinguish between syllables with and without tone?
I was looking over Wikipedia's Syllable article, and it surprised me the precise level of terminology that exists to specify specific parts of syllables. The Chinese model section shows that the term syllable includes final, initial, and tone. I want to know if there is any terminology (even if esoteric) in English or Mandarin that specifies a final initial pair without the tone versus the syllable including the tone.

聲韻 shēngyùn has been used in Chinese linguistics for the combination of initial + final, and in my experience excludes the tone. However this is likely a case of your mileage may vary.
